# Prove that if $A^2+I=0$ then $A$ is similar over $\mathbb{R}$ to this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> $A$ is a matrix which satisfies $A^2 + I = 0$. Prove that $A$ is of even order $2k$ and $A$ is similar over $\mathbb{R}$ to 
>   $$\begin{bmatrix}
>   0 & I  \\
>   -I & 0 \\ 
>  \end{bmatrix}$$
>   where $I$ is the identity matrix of order $k$.

I could do the even thing as characteristic polyomial would be some power of minimal polynomial which is $x^2 + 1$ over $\mathbb{R}$. But how to do the next one ?

Comment: Hint: Make your space into a complex vector space by defining $(a+ib)x:=ax+bAx$.

Comment: One key here is that since the minimal polynomial is $(x-i)(x+i)$ you know that $A$ is diagonalisable over $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treating $A$ as a matrix with complex entries, let $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ be a basis for the eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $i$. Then $\{\overline{v_1}, \ldots, \overline{v_n}\}$ is a basis for the eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\overline{i} = -i$. Define
$$ w_j := \mathrm{Re}(v_j) = \frac{v_j + \overline{v_j}}{2}, u_j := \mathrm{Im}(v_j) = \frac{v_j - \overline{v_j}}{2i}. $$
Check that $(w_1, \ldots, w_n, u_1, \ldots, u_n)$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and then check how $A$ acts on this basis.